# getting throttle exception while using aws describe_log_streams

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Below is my boto3 code snippet for lambda. My requirement is to read the entire cloudwatch logs and based on certain criteria should push it to S3.

I have used the below snippet to read the cloudwatch logs from each stream. This is working absolutely fine, for lesser data. However for massive logs inside each LogSteam this will throw

> Throttle exception - (reached max retries: 4)
>   Default/Max value is 50.

I tried given certain other values but of no use. Please check and let me know if there is any other alternative for this?

```
while v_nextToken is not None:
    cnt+=1
    loglist += '\n' +  "No of iterations inside describe_log_streams 2nd stage - Iteration Cnt" + str(cnt)
    #Note : Max value of limit=50 and by default value will be 50
    #desc_response = client.describe_log_streams(logGroupName=vlog_groups,orderBy='LastEventTime',nextToken=v_nextToken,descending=True, limit=50)
    try:
        desc_response = client.describe_log_streams(logGroupName=vlog_groups,orderBy='LastEventTime',nextToken=v_nextToken,descending=True, limit=50)
    except Exception as e:
        print ( "Throttling error" + str(e) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CW logs [subscription filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html) for Lambda, so the lambda will be triggered directly from the log stream. You can also consider subscribing a Kinesis stream which has some advantages.